# How to create subscription for all values in parameter?

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I have power bi report server paginated report with 1 multi select parameter (Client).

I have created subscription and in it I have selected the `(Select all)` option.

The problem is that when a new client is created then it isn't automatically included in the subscription. Is there any way to fix this?